PyAutoGUI locateAllOnScreen can't circumvent ImageNotFoundException
I am coding a small script to automize an annoying task in a game. To do that, I need to compare screenshots. When I used LocateCenterOnScreen, it worked just fine, with the exception that it only found the very first occurence. But I want all occurences, so I changed it to locateAllOnScreen. But when I do, and there is none on screen, it throws the ImageNotFoundException and tells me to lower the confidence (there is no match, I checked manually, so lowering the confidence wouldn't be what I want)
Can I somehow catch the Exceptions to keep it running?
Error Message:
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\LeafBlowerTrade\main.py", line 31, in start
    for pos in locs:
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\LeafBlowerTrade\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 257, in _locateAll_opencv
    raise ImageNotFoundException('Could not locate the image (highest confidence = %.3f)' % result.max())
pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException: Could not locate the image (highest confidence = 0.550)

This is what I try in my code, but it doesn't work. That exact same code worked, when I used locateCenterOnScreen instead.
try:
  locs = locateAllOnScreen(icon, confidence=0.6)
except ImageNotFoundException:
  pass

The whole code is:
from pyautogui import *
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


TOGGLE_KEY = KeyCode(char="p")

running = False
mouse = Controller()


def toggle_event(key):
    if key == TOGGLE_KEY:
        global running
        running = not running
        print(position())


def start():
    icon = 'Gem.png'
    while True:
        if running:
            locs = []
            try:
                locs = locateAllOnScreen(icon, confidence=0.6)
            except ImageNotFoundException:
                pass
            for pos in locs:
                x = pos[0] + int(pos[2] / 2)
                y = pos[1] + int(pos[3] / 2)
                moveTo(x + 768, y)
                mouse.press(Button.left)
                time.sleep(0.02)
                mouse.release(Button.left)
            moveTo(1557, 1124)
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            time.sleep(0.02)
            mouse.release(Button.left)
            moveTo(606, 1126)
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            time.sleep(0.02)
            mouse.release(Button.left)
            moveTo(2008, 1123)
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            time.sleep(0.02)
            mouse.release(Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.1)


run_thread = threading.Thread(target=start)
run_thread.start()

with Listener(on_press=toggle_event) as listener:
    listener.join()

The working code with locateCenterOnScreen is:
from pyautogui import *
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


TOGGLE_KEY = KeyCode(char="p")

running = False
mouse = Controller()


def toggle_event(key):
    if key == TOGGLE_KEY:
        global running
        running = not running
        print(position())


def start():
    icon = 'Gem.png'
    while True:
        if running:
            try:
                position = locateCenterOnScreen(icon, confidence=0.7)
                x, y = position
                moveTo(x+768, y)
                mouse.press(Button.left)
                time.sleep(0.02)
                mouse.release(Button.left)
                moveTo(1557, 1124)
                mouse.press(Button.left)
                time.sleep(0.02)
                mouse.release(Button.left)
                moveTo(606, 1126)
                mouse.press(Button.left)
                time.sleep(0.02)
                mouse.release(Button.left)
            except ImageNotFoundException:
                moveTo(606, 1126)
                mouse.press(Button.left)
                time.sleep(0.02)
                mouse.release(Button.left)
            moveTo(2008, 1123)
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            time.sleep(0.02)
            mouse.release(Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.1)


run_thread = threading.Thread(target=start)
run_thread.start()

with Listener(on_press=toggle_event) as listener:
    listener.join()

Edit:
It is not a perfect solution, but I have managed to do it.
The way I solved it is to check for locateCenterOnScreen first.
So instead of:
try:
  locs = locateAllOnScreen(icon, confidence=0.6)
except ImageNotFoundException:
  pass

I used:
try:
  posit = locateCenterOnScreen(icon, confidence=0.7)
except ImageNotFoundException:
  pass
if posit:
  locs = locateAllOnScreen(icon, confidence=0.7)
  for pos in locs:


Firstly, try doing
try:
    locs = locateAllOnScreen(icon, confidence=0.6)
except pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException:
    pass

Sometimes, specifying exactly what exception you want to avoid can help fix the problem.
Another way you could fix the problem is by using your locateCenterOnScreen and creating a new image with that region covered. You can accomplish this by using the cv2.rectangle method and providing a new image back into the loop. This is a much more complex approach and don’t think it is necessary.
A second solution while using locateCenterOnScreen would be to check the screen in a grid style. For example:
def start():
icon = 'Gem.png'

# Replace img_x and img_y with Gem.png’s x and y.
# The first region will be [0,0,img_x,img_y].
reg = (0,0,img_x,img_y)

while True:
    if running:
        try:
            position = locateCenterOnScreen(icon, region=reg, confidence=0.7)
            x, y = position
            # rest of your code here

            change_reg = list(reg)
            change_reg[0], change_reg[2] = int(change_reg[0]) + img_x, int(change_reg[2]) + img_x
            reg = tuple(change_reg)
         except ImageNotFoundException:
            # rest of your code

            change_reg = list(reg)
            change_reg[0], change_reg[2] = int(change_reg[0]) + img_x, int(change_reg[2]) + img_x
            reg = tuple(change_reg)

This isn’t the exact code, but it’s relatively close; you’d have to modify it to be able to change the y values once it surpasses the screen.
I don’t currently have a computer to try these out so they might not work as intended or at all. Sorry!

To get the region of your image, you can do ‘pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1,y1,x2,y2))’ and then save the image, until you see gem.img. After that, do x2-x1 to get img_x and y2-y1 to get img_y.

As the other locate functions throw a pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException but the locateAllOnScreen() throws a pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException , I treat this as a bug.
